# add objects to mutable array from a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have NSMutable dictionary like this

```
[dict setObject:arrItems forKey:@"Added"];
```

where "arrItems" is an array, so my dictionary contains arrays.
Problem is how can I retrieve real objects from dictionary. not as array objects.

when I tried like this

```
[myArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Added"]];
```

It's added objects to myArray as complete "arrItems" array. I want to add objects of arrItems to myArray.

Please give me a help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `[myArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Added"]]`

I recommend you learn to use the documentation, as this is clearly documented in the NSArray documentation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. its ok now. :) still Im quit new to iPhone SDK, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `addObjectsFromArray:` selector like so which will append the Objects retrieved from the array stored in the Dictionary (arrItems) to the end of myArray:

```
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Added"]];
```

You can find more information on [Apple's Documentation on NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
[myArray addObject:[(NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"Added"] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through arrItems and add them individually which is the simplest solution.

However i think you can type cast the returned object from the dictionary into a NSArray and then create a new array with it.

```
NSArray *anArray = (NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"Added"];
NSMutableArray * myArray  = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:anArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[dict objectForKey@"Added]` returns an `NSArray` object?

So, if you want to add an object of the `NSArray`, you need to call something like that

`[[dict objectForKey@"Added] objectAtIndex:index]`